# Как просмотреть chrome.storage.sync

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, localstorage

Разрабатываю расширение для Chrome. Сохраняю через код расширения данные в chrome.storage.sync. Можно ли их как-то просматривать и редактировать через GUI или же только посредством вызова методов api?

Comment: А в чем проблема самому сделать GUI, в своем же расширении? Вы же разработчик, вам и карты в руки. API есть, остальное - дело техники.

Comment: Ну, здравый смысл подсказывает, что он уже где-то есть и я его тупо не могу найти в инструментах браузера. Соотвественно, зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать в Extensions / Inspect Views: background page, F12 - https://ui.vision/howto/view-local-storage

Comment: Такого интерфейса внутри не существует, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользуюсь несколько лет, правда для local, а не sync - прекрасная штука.

Comment: А то, что оно 3 года не обновлялось ему не вредит?

Comment: Мне не вредит. API и спецификация вроде за три года не менялось. С local работает отлично.